# Is there any way I can maintain password history of a user in ASP.Net application?

Tags: asp.net

I need to view users password history in an ASP.net application.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain that as an encrypted string in your backend. Meaning in the database or some file system (not recommended).

Comment: Understood, I would like to know is there any out of the box provided by asp.net to check for the user password history?

Since I want to check some old password against the new password of a user try to reset password.

Comment: @user536320 - I do not think there is any such inbuilt feature for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

In fact, storing plain passwords is the worst approach in terms of security.

Administrator must not have access to plain passwords, this the reason of most of applications prompts you to create a new one, because passwords are hashed and hashing prevents from reverting to plain text.

If you need to track passwords, you'll need to write a custom membership provider tracking them.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into .Net that will provide this information. You would have to write your own solution to create an audit trail of passwords but this would involve storing passwords in a visible format. Remember the massive caveat about plain passwords though!

So long as you're only doing this for old passwords i.e. storing them **AFTER** the user has set a new password it should be ok.

Comment: You should never record passwords in plain text, even old ones. Storing old ones in plain text would give administrators clues as to what the new password may be. E.g. if they have used mydogsname1, mydogsname2, mydogsname3 then it'd be easy to figure out the current password.